Having trouble iteratively reading from Word document and adding to an excel file
Working on a way to read from a Word document and export contents to Excel.  I have tried creating a list in Python and then appending the text that I read to the list, but I keep getting error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'.  I read the python-docx help files and have not found anything that helps me.
The test Word file is pretty simple and if I comment out the code that is throwing the errors, then I can read the file and print to the screen so I know that this part of the code is working.
Here is the code that I have written:
from docx import Document
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd


Excel_File = "Heading and text import.xlsx"

# Define some initial variables
Req_Name=''
Req_Text=''


data = [['Req_Name', 'Req_Text']]

#Create a new Excel workbook
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
#Select the default sheet (usually named 'Sheet')
sheet = (workbook.active)



# Open the Word document
document = Document('Heading and text import.docx')


# Define the function that will read in the headings from the Word document
def iter_headings(paragraphs):
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'):
            yield paragraph

for heading in iter_headings(document.paragraphs):
    print (heading.text)
    #Req_Name.extend(paragraph.text) # this gives me this error --> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'
    # OR this line of code
    #Req_Name.append(paragraph.text) # this gives me this error --> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Req_Name


# Define the function that will read in the paragraph text from the Word document
def iter_text(paragraphs):
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Normal'):
            yield paragraph

            
# Read in the document text
for paragraph in iter_text(document.paragraphs):
    print (paragraph.text)


# # Some clean up
# workbook.save(Excel_File)
# workbook.close()
# # document.Close()
# # word.Quit()

I have tried both append and extend, but I am getting this error message:
#Req_Name.extend(paragraph.text) # this gives me this error --> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'extend'
# OR this line of code
#Req_Name.append(paragraph.text) # this gives me this error --> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

I wonder if I am not defining the list correctly or should I be using tuples instead......

Req_Name is a string: Req_Name=''. append() and extend() are list methods.

If it's supposed to be a list, use Req_Name = []
